How can I use an SQL 'in' clause with potentially empty list parameter in Java JPA?
I have a JPA repository interface with the following method:
@Modifying
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM bivrip.bloop_options o WHERE o.bloop_id = ?1 AND o.id not in ?2", nativeQuery = true)
public void removeOtherOptions(int bloopID, List<Integer> validOptionIDs);

When the validOptionIDs contains at least one element, the method behaves as expected and removes all ids not in the list associated with the given bloop.  However, if the list is empty, it doesn't delete anything - when I would assume it would delete all options for the provided bloop.
Do I need to do anything extra configuration-wise in order to make this work?  Or am I condemned to writing another method along the lines of "removeAllOptionsForBloop"?
Note: If this should generally work and is a result of particular database implementation, I'm using postgres.

(?2 is null or o.id not in ?2) ?

Simple and easy, thanks.  Looks like I can't accept a comment as the answer - if you want to post this as yours I'll accept it if you care about that...

Happy to help. I just added as answer.

Rewrite the query to use an array parameter and the <> ALL operator:
... AND o.id <> ALL (?2)

That will work for empty arrays as well.

You can try to use JpaSpecificationExecutor if you like, I think It is better because you have more control of your query and you don't need to write native SQL.
public interface BloopOptionRepository extends JpaRepository<BloopOption, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<BloopOption> {

}

public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    private BloopOptionRepository bloopOptionRepository;

    //You can move to another class Like BloopOptionQuerySpecification
    private static Specification<BloopOption> bloopId(int bloopId) {
        return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) ->
                criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("bloopId"), bloopId);
    }

    private static Specification<BloopOption> notInOptionIds(List<Integer> optionIds) {
        return  (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> criteriaBuilder.notIn(root.get("id")).value(optionIds);
    }

    public void removeOtherOptions(int bloopID, List<Integer> validOptionIDs) {
        Specification<BloopOption> spec = Optional.ofNullable(validOptionIDs)
                .filter(ids -> !ids.isEmpty())
                .map(ids -> bloopId(bloopID).and(notInOptionIds(ids)))
                .orElseGet(() -> bloopId(bloopID));
        bloopOptionRepository.delete(spec);
    }
}


Simplest possible way of solving this is:
(?2 is null or o.id not in ?2)

Essentially what this does is to use the Boolean table to validate the conditions, if the first check evaluates to true it skips the second, hence if the first parameter is not provided (hence null) it will bypass the IN condition.
Added as an answer as requested by OP.

It would be great if the Downvoter add a reason so I can improve upon it. Thanks.
